# Detect sudden change in current and send signal to arduino

Tags: arduino, charger, linear, socket, smart

I am trying to make a smart power socket using Arduino.

The socket should power even high power equipments at 230 Volt 50hz through a relay.
I want my arduino to analyse the amount of current taken by the equipment, so that when there is a sudden drop in current taken by the equipment , the arduino will switch off the relay.

The idea is that when a charger finish charging a device ,there will be drop in current taken and so it can be turned off.Or in case of a TV when it is switched off by remote there will be a drop in current and the relay will switch off to conserve energy.

I know how t o connect and program but don't know how to detect the drop in current and send signal to aruino. It will also be fine if I can linearly decrease current and voltage so that it is compatible with arduino.

Comment: The real question is, how will the arduino know when to switch  the relay back on again when the user wants to charge another device or turn their TV back on?

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about the range of power you expect (when device is 'on'. If it's not orders of magnitude, them you can
Use a current transformer to sense current, then a rectifier, filter, signal conditioning to get average or peak value which can be fed to the ADC.

There are also single chip solutions which will give you all the data over a serial line (see MAXQ314, for example).